# reshape dataframe with various length rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in python that looks like this:

```
ID    Value
001   0.5
001   0.2
001   0.5
001   0.0
002   0.4
002   0.6
002   0.6
```

I would like the data to be reshaped into something like this:

```
ID    Val1    Val2   Val3   Val4
001   0.5     0.2    0.5    0.0
002   0.4     0.6    0.6    NaN
```

Can anyone help with this? My first thought was de-melting the data with "pivot" but without a value denoting the "Val" position, it doesnt work as intended.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouppby your `ID` then reset the index to keep the columns consistent and unstack

```
df.groupby('ID')['Value'].apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack()
      0    1    2    3
ID
1   0.5  0.2  0.5  0.0
2   0.4  0.6  0.6  NaN
```

OR to not use `ID` as the index:

```
df.sort_values('ID').groupby('ID')['Value'].apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().reset_index()
  ID    0    1    2    3
0  1  0.5  0.2  0.5  0.0
1  2  0.4  0.6  0.6  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) an indexer series, then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
res = df.assign(ValNum=df.groupby('ID').cumcount()+1)\
        .pivot(index='ID', columns='ValNum', values='Value')\
        .reset_index()

print(res)

ValNum  ID    1    2    3    4
0        1  0.5  0.2  0.5  0.0
1        2  0.4  0.6  0.6  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["001"]*4 + ["002"]*3, "value": [0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0.0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6]})
>>> df
    id  value
0  001    0.5
1  001    0.2
2  001    0.5
3  001    0.0
4  002    0.4
5  002    0.6
6  002    0.6
>>> pd.concat([pd.Series(list(g["value"]), name=x) for x, g in df.groupby("id")], axis=1).T
       0    1    2    3
001  0.5  0.2  0.5  0.0
002  0.4  0.6  0.6  NaN
```

Now what you have to do is to rename the columns/rows.